# Media file can not be switched and played

Tags: c++, symbian, nokia, s60

I am trying to play a music file on S60 5th edition with the following code:

```
_LIT(KMusicFilename, "C:\\Data\\Music.mp3");

 TApaTaskList iTaskList(CCoeEnv::Static()->WsSession());
 TBool iExists;
 TApaTask iApaTask = iTaskList.FindApp(TUid::Uid(0x102072C3));
 iExists = iApaTask.Exists();
 if(iExists)
   {
   // Music player already running
   iApaTask.SwitchOpenFile(KMusicFilename);
   iApaTask.BringToForeground();
   }
 else
   {
   // music player is not running and needs to be launched
   RApaLsSession iAplsSession;
   User::LeaveIfError(iAplsSession.Connect());
   TThreadId thread;
   iAplsSession.StartDocument( KMusicFilename, 
                               thread, 
                               RApaLsSession::ESwitchFiles );
   iAplsSession.Close();
   }
```

The problem is that this code sample does not work if the music player is already running. The media file that was already playing keeps playing, the function `SwitchOpenFile` does not have any effect on it.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but one thing I notice about your code: this call:

```
iApaTask.SwitchOpenFile(KMusicFilename);
```

does not check the error code; see if you get an non-zero error code and this may help determine what the problem is. (The same applies to the `iAplsSession.StartDocument(...)` call).

Comment: I did check the return value while debugging, and it is KErrNone.